# Python requests file but where does it go

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Lets say I do this

```
r = requests.get(url)
with open("file.py", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
    f.close
```

This will create and write the content of the file i requested into file.py
But when I only does this

```
r = requests.get(url)
#and i run my code
```

Will it take up my pc storage if I keep on requesting but didn’t write it into a file

Comment: It will not be written to your PC hard drive.  But it will take up memory for as long as the program runs.

Comment: No, each time `r = requests.get(url)` is executed, any previous value assigned to `r` will be discarded (and likely eventually garbage-collected).

Answer (score 0):

When you run `r = requests.get(url)`, the response will be stored in that variable, r. Any variable storing data will take up space on your computer, but not anything large enough to care about. If you run your code multiple times, the data in the variable r will just be overwritten. There is no reason to write data to an actual file unless you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not write the content of the request into any file, your storage will not be affected. Your RAM is the one that holds the content from the request. RAM memory will only be used up by a program for as long as it runs. When your code finishes the RAM will be released.